# Link Google Code to SO Careers Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I just noticed this feature next to the github link. Kudos. Very excited to try it out. But I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if it's broken.

I finally found the @garbage for my account (could you just take /u/username instead since that's a valid URL?) and I have owner, committer, and starred various projects, but clicking the Get Projects button gives me no love. No error, either.

**Update:** I should have specified before that the example URL works for me; it shows several projects. It's my own profile that shows no results (not even a "no results" message).

PEBKAC, bug, or other?

Comment: I just used the /u/username link, and it worked fine.

Comment: Then maybe it's me? I get no results either way. Or maybe it's my browser? Google Chrome on Ubuntu and Chrome OS are what I've tried so far.

Comment: What's the URL? I will test it out.

Comment: @Matt http://code.google.com/u/@UxRfR1JYBxBCVgV%2F/

Comment: OK thanks, fix is in the queue, will be online tomorrow. That encoded bit at the end was tripping us up... here's the solution if curious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781205/c-net-getting-a-url-with-an-url-encoded-slash

Comment: Awesome. What's the procedure for closing this question? Do I just let it fade away?

Comment: I'll tag the question [status-completed] when the fix is confirmed.

Comment: I tried the /u/@ URL format and it worked! /u/username behavior is unchanged for me - no visible response.

Comment: I suppose it's an item worth noting that the example URL from http://careers.stackoverflow.com/import/google/53945 , http://code.google.com/u/@VxdTRlxUDhBEXAh8/ , does not work for me (returns a 404). The actual import did not work with my username, but did with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was Google's unusual URL -- the last bit looks encoded and my HTTP client was decoding by default. This should be good now.

Comment: Thanks again, Matt. Is the "code.google.com/u/username" URL form supported? Jon Skeet said it worked for him, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: If you are logged into Google Code, it's the Profile link in the upper right header. Sometimes the URL looks like a user name, sometimes it doesn't, but that's the link we need.

Comment: Right. I know what page we're talking about. I'm sorry if I'm not stating this clearly. I'll try again. If I use http://code.google.com/u/@UxRfR1JYBxBCVgV%2F/ to import projects into Careers, it works (as of today, thanks to your fix). If I use http://code.google.com/u/itruett/ then it doesn't work, but it sounds like you're saying that it should. Both of those URLs, in my browser, show the same page. Should I open a new bug for the second URL?

Comment: The code.google.com/u/itruett URL is a 404 for me. Maybe it only works for the logged-in user. The page to use is the one I describe above.

Comment: I dug around and figured it out. Posted an answer in case this was bugging anyone else.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the scoop on the `/u/username` URLs.

When logged into your Google account, go to `https://code.google.com/hosting/settings` and look for this option under Privacy:

> When I participate in projects, show non-members my email address as "foo...@gmail.com"

If this option is checked, `http://code.google.com/u/foobar` will work for you when you are logged into your Google account. It will not work for anyone else, returning 404 instead. It also won't work for adding Google Code projects to your Careers profile.

With the option unchecked, the `/u/foobar` becomes valid for the rest of the world and you show up as "foobar" to the general public on Google Code. That shorter URL form then works for adding Google Code projects to your Careers profile.

Comment: They succeeded in making it complicated! So caveat emptor if one insists on using the username.